# Remove quotes from json_encoded ints prior to 5.3.3

Tags: php, json

When using json_encode, it annoyingly automatically coverts the int keys to strings. For example, if you have an array:

```
$a = array(); 
$a[12] = 15;
echo json_encode($a);
{"12":15} //notice the quotes around 12
```

After searching SO, the solution is to use

```
json_encode($array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
```

However, that is only available in php > 5.3.3. The production server I'm stuck with is using 5.3.2.

Surely there is a work around?

Comment: It wouldn't remove the quotes around the object key anyway. That's not valid in a JSON serialization (only in JSOL).

Comment: Just implement an own JSON encoder. It's not _that_ difficult, since JSON is a pretty primitive format.

Comment: Leave the quotes there and parse/cast it when necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20131740/1064325

Comment: @mario - you are correct. The JSON spec requires the key to be a string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that you are basically mixing your approach to the data structure and `json_encode()` is trying to make a best guess as to how to interpret your array, since in JSON, there is not such concept of a non-zero based, numerically indexed array.

If for example, you had a zero-based numeric array with a continuous number sequence, `json_encode()` would encode this a a numerically-indexed array of the format:

```
[value1, value2, ...]
```

Since you don't have a zero-based array, your data structure is being interpreted as an object structure and given a string key (the only available key type for an object in JSON) of the format:

```
{"key", value}
```

So it seems you need to make up your mind as to what you are really trying to represent in your array.  Do you only need a numerically based array, or do you need object encoding.

Comment: Yep, I was unaware that JSON required the key to be a string.